# Average size of intersection of random samples drawn from the same population

Tags: python-3.x, math, combinations, probability, intersection

Let say we have an urn with N balls, and we draw several random samples of random size from this urn (we replace the balls in the urn after each sampling but each sample is drawn without replacement).

I need to **compute the average size of each sample after removing elements that are at least in 2 samples**.

For example, if the N = 2 and we have one sample of 1 element and one sample of 2 elements, average size after removing intersection will be 0 for the first sample and 1 for the last one.

If N = 3, and first sample has 1 element and second sample has 2 elements, I think the element in first sample have 2/3 chance of being in other sample, so the *size* of first sample would be 1/3, and the size of second sample 1 + 1/3 = 4/3.

I'm struggling to find a formula to compute this for any situation, I guess it can be done with number of combinations and sizes of samples.

I have small values for N (less than 100), for the samples sizes (less than 10) and for the number of samples (2, 3 or 4)...

I could approximate this easily with some Monte Carlo simulation (see code below) but it would be faster to apply directly the correct formula.

Maybe this would be more understandable with some python code which compute some approximations of what I want:

```
from random import sample, randint


def simulations(population_size, samples_sizes, iterations_count=10000):
    population = range(population_size)
    samples_count = len(samples_sizes)
    average_intersection_size = [0 for _ in range(samples_count)]
    for iteration in range(1, iterations_count + 1):  # start from 1
        # generate random samples
        samples = []
        for sample_index in range(samples_count):
            samples.append(sample(population, samples_sizes[sample_index]))
        # count items overlapping
        for sample_index in range(samples_count):
            # retrieve intersection size with the union of other samples
            union_of_others = set()
            for other_sample_index in range(samples_count):
                if other_sample_index == sample_index:
                    # we skip current sample
                    continue
                union_of_others |= set(samples[other_sample_index])
            n = len(set(samples[sample_index]) & union_of_others)
            # incremental mean...
            delta = n - average_intersection_size[sample_index]
            average_intersection_size[sample_index] += delta / iteration
    # output results
    print(f'population size is {population_size}')
    for sample_index in range(samples_count):
        print(
f'sample {sample_index + 1}: original_size={samples_sizes[sample_index]}, new_size={samples_sizes[sample_index] - average_intersection_size[sample_index]}')


population_size = 12
samples_count = randint(2, 4)
samples_sizes = [randint(1, population_size) for _ in range(samples_count)]

simulations(population_size, samples_sizes)

"""Example outputs

population size is 12
sample 1: original_size=10, new_size=1.859099999999989
sample 2: original_size=4, new_size=0.18249999999999833
sample 3: original_size=7, new_size=0.51390000000002
sample 4: original_size=4, new_size=0.1847000000000114

population size is 12
sample 1: original_size=1, new_size=0.4761000000000001
sample 2: original_size=5, new_size=3.821899999999997
sample 3: original_size=2, new_size=1.0762999999999967

population size is 12
sample 1: original_size=4, new_size=0.0
sample 2: original_size=4, new_size=0.0
sample 3: original_size=6, new_size=0.0
sample 4: original_size=12, new_size=2.6712000000000167

population size is 12
sample 1: original_size=8, new_size=7.335500000000002
sample 2: original_size=1, new_size=0.33550000000000246

population size is 12
sample 1: original_size=9, new_size=0.7495999999999565
sample 2: original_size=11, new_size=2.7495999999999565
"""
```

My goal is to avoid simulations and applying the exact formula directly instead.

Comment: As you do *not* want to use code to solve this problem, maybe it is more of a question for the [Math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @DavidWierichs Sure but I'll finally use the formula in my code. I'm more a code person than a math one and I'm afraid if I post in the Math stack exchange I won't be able to correctly understand answers (if some) and translate it to code :)

Comment: I understand that issue, but the resource you want to access might be there and not here. I'll think about this one a bit.

Comment: I agree that this is more suitable for math.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com. Also, I think this is similar to the "catch and release" problem (e.g. tagging fish or animals) which I'm pretty sure has some known results.